# Testing web service using C#

Tags: c#, web-services, testing

We need to test a web service which accepts JSON request. Server is implemented with WCF and REST API . Server response is asynchronous. I am thinking of below approach:

Approach 1: Use System.web and call UploadStringAsync

Approach 2: User asynchronous delegates in c#

I need to match response from server with request sent.

Is there any other better way to test REST API.
I need to develop test framework to test web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One part of testing a web service is testing what the web service *does*. You can do that with standard unit testing frameworks. This sort of testing has nothing to do with JSON or HTTP or REST, and that's a good thing. It will ensure that your service will work once you give it the correct JSON or HTTP or REST.

After you have tested the functionality of the service, you may want to write some other tests to make sure that the JSON, HTTP and REST part works. For that, you might use `WebRequest` or `WebClient`, or Visual Studio Web Tests.

Comment: Unit testing would be a black box approach. I am from test automation team. I need to come up with black box approach. Can I test functionality using WebClient or WebRequest ?

Comment: Of course, you can. In fact, you should look into Web Tests. They will be able to do some of the work for you. If you'll be doing a lot of this testing, you may find the extensibility useful to you, as you would be able to create custom adapters for various things. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee923683.aspx